# How do I set up a slot (event handler) that takes parameters, using gtk.go.Connect()?

Tags: event-handling, go, gtk, go-gtk

I am using [**GTK bindings for Go**](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk).

Trying to connect a `gtk.RadioButton` `toggle` signal to a function. This code works fine:

```
...

radioButton.Connect("toggled", doRadioToggle)

func doRadioToggle() {
    fmt.Println("toggled")
}

...
```

When radioButton is toggled, doRadioToggle is called - Good.

---

But I want to connect to a function that takes a parameter, for example:

```
func doRadioToggle(button *gtk.RadioButton) {
    fmt.Println(button.GetState())
}
```

The `gtk.go.Connect()` function has this signature:

```
func (v *Widget) Connect(s string, f interface{}, datas ...interface{})
```

Based on what I know from gtkmm, I tried code like this (the go binding has apparently greatly simplified the call to connect())

```
radioButton.Connect("toggled", doRadioToggle, radioButton)
```

The third argument passed in`connect()` - `radioButton` - corresponding to`datas`in

`gtk.Connect(s string, f interface{}, datas ...interface{})`

which I understood to mean data arguments to be passed to the slot.

But with this code, the doRadioToggle() handler never gets called, and I immediately exit with a panic:

```
panic: reflect: Call using *glib.CallbackContext as type *gtk.RadioButton
```

My question: How do I set up slot (event handler) that takes parameters using gtk.go.Connect()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on response from the amazing [**mattn**](https://github.com/mattn) on GitHub:

[**https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/blob/master/example/demo/demo.go#L58**](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/blob/master/example/demo/demo.go#L58)

Adopted, tested and working:

```
import(
... 
"github.com/mattn/go-gtk/glib"
)

...

func ButtonHandler(ctx *glib.CallbackContext) {
    fmt.Printf("Button Handler: %v\n", ctx.Data().(*gtk.RadioButton).GetState())
}

aRadioButton.Connect("toggled", ButtonHandler, aRadioButton)

...
```

The`datas`arguments in`connect()`must be passed using`*glib.CallbackContext` in the handler's signature, then, in the handler code, use type assertion to grab the actual arguments .

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not clear about how to pass additional data directly; perhaps simply use a closure instead.

https://godoc.org/github.com/mattn/go-gtk/glib#CallbackContext

Comment: See my posted answer. The docs you cited aren't quite clear about this.